# MongoDB push into nested array without using indices

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking to `$push` something into a nested array, of which the parent array matches a simple property condition:

Here's how my document looks:

```js
{
  name: "Foo",
  boardBucket: {
    currentBoardId: 1234,
    items: [ <- looking to push into `boardItems` of an `item` in this Array
      { 
        boardId: 1234, <- that has `boardId: 1234` 
        boardItems: [ "barItem", "deyItem" ] <- Final Array I want to push to
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I'd like to push `"fooItem"` in `boardItems` of `item` that has `boardId: 1234`

**Option 1:  I can use dot notation and access by index**

I can certainly do a `$push` by using dot.notation which uses the index of the item like so:

```js
this.update({ '$push': {"boardBucket.items.0.boardItems": "fooItem" } });
```

**But what if I don't know the index?**

How can I push into `boardItems` of `item` with `boardId: 1234` *without* using the indices (using the `boardId` instead)?

---

Note:

- I'm using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) as the db driver
- I'd like to avoid using mongoose's `save()` cause it tends to be buggy + it seems to keep a copy of the object locally which i'd like to avoid
- Just direct `update()` mongo queries are what I'm after
- I'd certainly like to avoid any type of whole-document fetching to perform this update as my documents are huge in size

Comment: You can use position operator ($).

Comment: @CetinBasoz thanks - It's not clear from the docs how that would work in this case - can you add a minimal example as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do the trick:

```
this.update(
  {"boardBucket.items": {$elemMatch: { boardId: "1234"}}},
  {'$push': {"boardBucket.items.boardItems": "fooItem" }}
);
```

Comment: @CetinBasoz answer is more precise. My approach would push in to every boardBucket items array that has the "boardId": "1234".

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do as well - for some reason it throws `cannot use the part (items of boardBucket.items.boardId) to traverse the element`

Comment: I think you're missing a curly bracket after `{$elemMatch: { boardId: "1234"}}, `, should be `{$elemMatch: { boardId: "1234"}}},`

Comment: hate to be a pest but it doesn't seem to work - Although the query (with my corrected `}` addition) runs and returns `nModified : 1`, it doesn't seem to add `"fooItem"` anywhere in the DB (checked the entire DB in case it get's erroneously added somewhere else) - Note that the `boardId`'s definitely match so that's not the problem - any ideas?

Comment: I feel confident about this latest updated. You were right about the missing '}'. Sorry i can't set up an environment to test it out properly, but let me know how it goes.

Comment: I confirm that: {'$push': {"boardBucket.items.boardItems": "fooItem" }} works

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry for not sampling in the first place, was on a rush then)

```
db.myDb.insert({
  name: "Foo",
  boardBucket: {
  currentBoardId: 1234,
    items: [ 
      { 
        boardId: 1234, 
        boardItems: [ "barItem", "deyItem" ] 
      },
      { 
        boardId: 1235, 
        boardItems: [ "dontPushToThisOne" ] 
      }
    ]
  }
});

db.myDb.insert({
  name: "Foo2",
  boardBucket: {
    currentBoardId: 1236,
    items: [ 
      { 
        boardId: 1236, 
        boardItems: [ "dontPushToThisOne" ] 
      }
    ]
  }
});


db.myDb.update( 
   { "boardBucket.currentBoardId":1234,
     "boardBucket.items.boardId":1234},
   { "$push" : {"boardBucket.items.$.boardItems":"fooItem"} }, {multi:1} );
```

Comment: Awesome - Strangely enough I'm getting this error however: `cannot use the part (items of boardBucket.items.boardId) to traverse the element ({items: [ { boardId: "147813751944",", _id: ObjectId('57b6da3fb0fcf466044a4c20')} ]})` - Is it because `items` is an array?

Comment: That may be mongoose specific, I don't use it. I wrote and tested the code in default mongo shell. (you use the quotes around it, right?)